# bash script : unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'

Tags: bash

I'm getting error for the bash script

```
line 23: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ``'
line 26: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Script :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello World"



args=("$@")

echo $args

echo "First->"  ${args[0]} 
echo "Second->" ${args[1]}

i=0

for var in "${args[@]}"
do
  echo "${var}"

  if [ $i == 0 ]; then
    pwd
  fi

` 

done
```

Can you please help me to fix this error?

Comment: What does the stray \` mean before `done`?

Answer (score 2):

Delete the stray backtick `` ` `` at the bottom of the script.